# if check box one uncheck box two three four and five

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This is my check box code:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="display-ad-one" <?php if ( get_option('display-ad-one') == 1 || get_option('display-ad-one') == 'on' ) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> /></td>

<td><input type="checkbox" name="display-ad-two" <?php if ( get_option('display-ad-two') == 1 || get_option('display-ad-two') == 'on' ) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> /></td>

<td><input type="checkbox" name="display-ad-three" <?php if ( get_option('display-ad-three') == 1 || get_option('display-ad-three') == 'on' ) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> /></td>

<td><input type="checkbox" name="display-ad-four" <?php if ( get_option('display-ad-four') == 1 || get_option('display-ad-four') == 'on' ) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> /></td>

<td><input type="checkbox" name="display-ad-five" <?php if ( get_option('display-ad-five') == 1 || get_option('display-ad-five') == 'on' ) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> /></td>
```

so what I need to here to uncheck example: When I check one automatically uncheck box two three four and five?

**Thank You.**

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. The objective here is for others to help you fix **your code** when it doesn't work as expected

Comment: @charlietfl do you have to be an opposition to everything?

Comment: @ÖzgürCanKaragöz haven't opposed anything here. Simply stated facts about how the site works...and what is expected

Comment: @charlietfl The question is simple and clear. I gave the answer at the bottom.

Comment: @charlietfl Please try to help. Do not make the job hard.

Comment: i just have make this code, for that im asking help, my question is what more i need here when check box one automatically uncheck box two three four and five. thanks for everything.

Comment: @ÖzgürCanKaragöz I realize that it is reasonably straightforward however showing effort to solve own problem is still expected as outlined in the [help] *Give  a man a fish, or teach a man to fish??*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand the problem. Can do it this way.

```js
$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
    $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="display-ad-one" /></td>

<td><input type="checkbox" name="display-ad-two" /></td>

<td><input type="checkbox" name="display-ad-three" checked /></td>

<td><input type="checkbox" name="display-ad-four" checked /></td>

<td><input type="checkbox" name="display-ad-five" checked /></td>
```

Comment: You're welcome. I would write a description, but the friend below wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do it in this way.
I suggest using the same value for the `name` attribute and change the `value` attribute and use a `radio` button instead of a `checkbox`.

```html
<td><input type="radio" name="display-ad" value="one"/></td>

<td><input type="radio" name="display-ad" value="two"/></td>

<td><input type="radio" name="display-ad" value="three"/></td>

<td><input type="radio" name="display-ad" value="four"/></td>

<td><input type="radio" name="display-ad" value="five"/></td>
```

Comment: @Stronzi i hope this somehow helped you

Answer (score 0):

use [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) and `prop('checked', false)` to uncheck other then clicked checkbox. Here is the working example.

```js
$('input:checkbox').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="display-ad-one" checked />

<input type="checkbox" name="display-ad-two" />

<input type="checkbox" name="display-ad-three"  />

<input type="checkbox" name="display-ad-four" />

<input type="checkbox" name="display-ad-five" />
```